# shareSingle from react-native-share does not work for WhatsApp in Android 11

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-share

React Native Share singleShare is not working. Tried out everything as mentioned in the blog post here:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Still no luck. Please help.

Code snapshot:

```
let shareOptions = {
    title: 'Share via WhatsApp',
    message: 'Hey Check out this product',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    url: urlString,
    filename: 'Awesome_Product',
    social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
    whatsAppNumber: 'number',
  };

Share.shareSingle(shareOptions)
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      })
      .catch(_err => showToast('WhatsApp is not installed on the device.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually add the `<package android:name="com.whatsapp" />` to the android manifest?

```xml
<queries>
...
   <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
```